# How can I get my old homebrew mods working on my new Wii?

Tags: technical-issues, nintendo-wii, homebrew

I have two Wii consoles, my old one and a new one. The old one can't read disks (it makes clicking sounds) so I would like to move to the new one.

I have Homebrew set up on my old Wii, with downloaded mods on an SD card. When I put the SD card in my new Wii and go on Homebrew, none of the mods work, but if I swap it back, they still work on my old Wii.

How can I get my mods working on my new Wii?

---

Further clarifications upon request:

- Both Wiis are capable of playing Gamecube games.
- Serial numbers for both consoles:

  - New Wii: lu83699349
  - Old Wii: lu53920826.
- They both have the '7' in the box

Answer (score 2):

I have seen that you cant just transfer one SD card over from one system to the next.

I'm pretty sure you need to re-download the homebrew channel to the new Wii, but I could be wrong.

here is a video on how to do Wii homebrew

Comment: There is a man on YouTube called 'Modern Vintage Gamer' who specializes in homebrewing and mods. I have seen a video where he talks about how to homebrew a Wii and talks about sd cards.

Comment: Okay, I will go look at his video